# How to Address Noise Resulting from Inverse-Scaling for a Machine Learning Task

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm still a little unsure of whether questions like these belong on stackoverflow. Is this website *only* for questions with explicit code? The "How to Format" just tells me it should be a programming question, which it is. I will remove my question if the community thinks otherwise.

---

I have created a neural network and am predicting reasonable values for most of my data (the task is multi-variate time series forecasting).

I scale my data before inputting it using scikit-learn's MinMaxScaler(0,1) or MinMaxScaler(-1,1) (the two primary scalings I am using).

The model learns, predicts, and I inverse the scaling using MinMaxScaler()'s inverse_transform method to visually see how close my predictions were to the actual values. However, I notice that the inverse_scaled values for a particular part of the vector I predicted have now become very noisy. Here is what I mean (inverse_scaled prediction):

Left end: noisy; right end: not-so noisy.

[image]

I initially thought that perhaps my network didn't learn that part of the vector well, so is just outputting ~random values. BUT, I notice that the predicted values before the inverse scaling seem to match the actual values very well, but that these values are typically near 0 or -1 (lower limit of the feature scale) because of the fact that these values have a very large spread (unscaled mean= 1E-1, max= 1E+1 [not an outlier]). Example (scaled prediction):

[image]

So, when inverse transforming these values (again, often near -1 or 0), the transformed values exhibit loud noise, as shown in the images.

Questions:

1.) Should I be using a different scaler/scaling differently, perhaps one that exponentially/nonlinearly scales? MinMaxScaler() scales each column. Simply dropping the high-magnitude data isn't an option since they are real, meaningful data. 2.) What other solutions can help this?

Please let me know if you'd like anything else clarified.